# Is angular momentum independent of axis (if axis is parallel)?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, orbital-motion

I have been told this is true for the moon on this question:

[Angular momentum of orbiting + rotating body](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/440368/angular-momentum-of-orbiting-rotating-body?noredirect=1#comment988680_440368)

but I don't understand why it should work. Surely the axis must be chosen such that the entire body is rotating around it? Otherwise you could come up with any answer?

EDIT: I think the we must define angular momentum about a point, such as the centre of orbit, and *not* an axis, such as the axis of orbit. So for a body rotating about an axis passing through this point: $L = w_i \times{r_i}\times{w_i}$ over all $i$ but $w_i$ is constant, so $L = wr_i.r_i - r^2\cdot{w}$ which is $Iw$ where $I$ is the moment of inertia about axis of rotation.

we have to show that this works for when the axis is shifted away from the origin so that $w_i$ is no longer constant but undergoes a transformation depending on $r_i$, if this fact is indeed true.